# Select only half records from table group by Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

Name
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
C
C
C
D
D
D
D

I need out put like below

Name
A
B
C
C
C
D
D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I need out put from the table based on name..if Name A as 2 times in the table I need to show 1 time same way if Name C has 6 times I need to show 3 times

Comment: @FatemehAbdollahei - if you know the question is off-topic, please don't edit it as if the question is closed then your edit is approved (in that order), the question will enter a review queue to be reopened. [Your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18059157) doesn't stop the question being off-topic; you're best leaving it alone.

Comment: You can use `count` with `group by` then you can divide and show the result N times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `row_number` and `count` window functions to get a running count and a total count per value, respectively, and then compare them:

```
SELECT value
FROM   (SELECT value, 
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY vale) AS cnt,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value) AS rn
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rn <= (cnt / 2)
```